# Paypal Express checkout payment not working in iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I have integrated Express checkout.js SDK client-side REST in my hybrid application using ionic and Express checkout functionality is not working properly in iPhones (but working on Android devices). I am using the same code in the below documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client 
The issues facing in iPhones while doing payment with credit/debit cards are:

- Payment popup is not responsive in iPhones, especially in iPhone5 the popup is not completely visible to the user.
- Payment popup close button is not visible in iPhone 5. The button is visible in iPhone6 but sometimes the close function is not properly working.
- Not able to do payment. While clicking 'continue' button after entering all details(card information and billing info), the user again taken to the top of the page near country selection. Not able to close the payment popup by clicking outside the popup.
- Payment popup scroll is not properly working. Sometimes the scroll will be working with a delay. But will be scrolled to the top of the page if the user tries to navigate back or proceed payment.

Can someone please help me? I sent a message to PayPal support, but they are not responding. We are in a very tight schedule and any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Responsive Issue Sample #1]
[image: Responsive Issue Sample #2]

Answer (score -1):

The link you referred is to be used for website integration, if you want to use it in ionic, you should call the api via your server side and open the payment URL in ionic BrowserTab, this way the page will be rendered properly.The above link is used for website integration and it will open an lightbox pop for browser which may mot work properly for all devices.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @optimus, we will check it out and get back to you later.